# Getting asp error '800706be' while creating the object in include files

Tags: asp-classic, tridion

I have got ASP application, and let me clear all code is working fine in my old server.

We recently moved our application to windows 2008 server R2 SP1, now after the deployment, in our default.asp page we we including four different files, and the issue is with every file, so I am taking one file as example.

Main File (default.asp) has got below object creation code on the top.

```
<%
Dim objTdsComponentLink, objTdsPageLink
Set objTdsComponentLink = Server.CreateObject("cd_link.ComponentLink")
Set objTdsPageLink= Server.CreateObject("cd_link.PageLink")
%>
```

Here everything works fine and we can use the object without any error.

As told above we are including four different files and in every file we are creating new object for our PageLink service as below:

```
Set PageLink = Server.createObject("cd_link.PageLink")
<%  strURL = PageLink.GetLink("tcm:0-79-1", "tcm:79-64940-64", "", "", "more", True).URL%>
```

Issue is that if we try to declare new object as Set PageLink = Server.createObject("cd_link.PageLink"), it gives error. however if we use same object which is declared above in default.asp it work perfectly and if we use or try to create new object it give below error.

```
error '800706be'
/include/home/FuelIndex.asp, line 26
```

Are we missing some configuration/installation here and surprising why it works for main page (default.asp) objects as well as it is working fine our old setup.

Would appreciate if you can give some suggestions/solutions for above issue.

Thanks.

Comment: No clue about the error, but just wanted to remark that creating a new object should only be done once on the page for performance reasons. The creation of these objects is a heavy server action and it is intended to be reused on the page. So if you have a working object in the main page already, I would recommend reusing that in all your includes which would solve your issue at the same time.

Comment: Which Tridion version is it? And do you have the Tridion Content Delivery Linking service running?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you solve this? I've tried all the steps below and no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are on IIS7.
Make sure you have Server Side Includes turned on as a feature of your webserver role.  it is not turned on by default on server 2008 or newer machines.  Its under server configuration, add/remove roles for IIS.

Make sure that you have enabled parent paths on IIS if the include is indeed in a parent path. 
Make sure that your include code is correct in its syntax.  Might want to test out with the include virtual since its a bit more flexible (versus include file).

Lastly, make sure that your application pool is 32 bit if the component you are creating is 32 bit.  or 64 bit if that is what you are using.

Comment: hi Frank, I have done two things 1) Installed Server Side...do I need to restart the machine or IIS Reset will be fine 2) I have checked the application pool, it already running on 32 bit mode...I am not very much clear what you are trying to say here "Make sure that you have enabled parent paths on IIS if the include is indeed in a parent path. Make sure that your include code is correct in its syntax. Might want to test out with the include virtual since its a bit more flexible (versus include file)."...Would appreciate if you can clear it... I mean what changes do I need to do for this

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 and I have checked my Enable Parent Path is true...any thing other I need to check as problem still exists :(

Comment: Permissions.  Make sure that IUser / Network User/ IIS user have full permission to begin with.  If that works, then you know its permissions and then you can tweak (tighten) permissions accordingly.  If something runs on iis6 it will likely run on IIS7 without little chnage.  It really seems like you need to get the IIS box configured with permissions, appool settings, asp configuration, and make sure any COM objects your asp script is using are registered and have permissions set.